# How do I autopopulate FIRST dates in Excel from a user ID

Tags: excel, date, vlookup, min, auto-populate

I have two sheets in one workbook.

**Members:** 
[image]

**Shifts:**
[image]

I want to grab the FIRST date from "shift" and populate it to the "Member" sheet.

I believe I would use a MIN for the date, a VLOOKUP somewhere...not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it but you can give this a try. `=index(Shifts.Date.column,Match(Member.id.range,shifts.date.column, -1))`  Not sure if that will work but give it a try.  Index match works like this.

Index(Where to look, Match(What to Match, Where to look to matcht, match type)).  Also look at using it with Iferror - Iferror(Index(Match)))

Comment: This isn't it 100%, but you got me on the right track!

Comment: I created a pivot table with the shift dates minimum, and then indexed that